# Apache Camel Spring-WS route not initializing

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-ws

I'm struggling with a Spring-WS route I'd like to add in my Spring-boot application. I keep getting the following exception on startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instance of CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping found in Spring ApplicationContext. This bean is required for Spring-WS consumer support (unless the 'spring-ws:beanname:' URI scheme is used)
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.addEndpointMappingToConfiguration(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:142)
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.addConsumerConfiguration(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceComponent.createEndpoint(SpringWebserviceComponent.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:568)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

This is very odd, as I explicitly add the CamelEndpointMapping (which extends from CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping) in my Spring configuration like this:

```
@EnableWs
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(messageDispatcherServlet, "/soap/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public CamelEndpointMapping endpointMapping()
    {
        return new CamelEndpointMapping();
    }
}
```

My route:

```
@Component
public class MyRoutes extends RouteBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        from("spring-ws:soapaction:http://example.com/myservice")
         .to("log:cameltest?level=DEBUG");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? You can find full source of my sample project on GitHub: https://github.com/verhage/cameltest

Comment: Is your CamelEndpointMapping class extending CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping? ...Nevermind, yes it does. Just noticed it in your explanation. In your @Configuration class, try setting the return type to CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping rather than CamelEndpointMapping

Comment: How are you running this code? I get dependency issues when I downloaded it and tried to run it

Comment: Explicitly changing the return type to CamelSpringWSEndpointMapping doesn't help. @davidfrancis, did you fetch all dependencies with mvn?

Comment: Yes, although something may have gone wrong of course! How exactly are you running it?

Comment: I use IntelliJ, I import the maven project and run Application#main. Maybe you have a settings.xml in your repository pointing to repositories not containing all libs? It should be able to resolve everything from central.

Comment: I do the equivalent in Eclipse - but then when I run Application.main I get: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/core/NamingPolicy

Comment: That class is included in spring-core, which should be transitively included by camel-spring-boot...

Comment: OK i got past the dependency issue and ended up with the same problem as you - debugging it

Comment: Seems that the error is misleading - if you read this page: http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

Comment: Look for "endpointMapping" - it seems you need to use that because you are using "soapaction" type. That means not much to me, maybe those docs can help?

Comment: This gets it a bit further, change uri to: spring-ws:soapaction:XXX?endpointMapping=endpointMapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error message is misleading.
Your URL needs to look like this:

```
spring-ws:soapaction:XXX?endpointMapping=endpointMapping
```

(found by debugging SpringWebserviceComponent.addConsumerConfiguration and stepping through)

Comment: No problems, you're welcome - it was an interesting investigation ;]